# AppSettings en aplicación Windows Forms: Cómo leer AppSettings.config en .NET Winforms (con .NET CORE 6)

Tags: c#

Tengo un proyecto que estoy trabajando en Windows Forms, Con EF Core 6, C#, utilizando el patron de repositorio y unidad de trabajo.

El problema que tengo, es que quiero darle seguridad a mi aplicacion, sacando del codigo de la conexion manual que tengo ahorita en mi clase ApplicationDbContext y leer un archivo App.config pero me marca error.

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            // Esta es la linea que quiero dejar funcionando pero no me reconce el ConfigurationManager
            //optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
            ////ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CnxDXAProducSoft"].ConnectionString);


            // Esta linea la comentare por que incluire la cadena de conexion a un archivo App.config
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer
                    ("Server = xxx.xxx.50.xx,1433; Database=CUNI_M1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=qmasuser");
        }
    }
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0305  Using the generic type 'ConfigurationManager' requires 1 type arguments  DXAProducSoft.AccesoDatos   D:\GIT\dxaproducsoft\DXAProducSoft.AccesoDatos\Data\ApplicationDbContext.cs 252 Active

Comment: si tienes `using System.Configuration` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dos temas

- **TEMA 1: Configuracion de usuario y aplicacion en Winforms (lo que viene pode default)**
- **TEMA 2: Leer appSettings.json desde Winform/Consola**

**TEMA 1: Configuracion de usuario y aplicacion en Winforms (lo que viene pode default)**

Primeramente te comento que Windows Forms tuiene su propio sistemas de "Configuracion" (identico al de .NET Framework)

- [Utilizar valores de configuración de aplicación y de usuario](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Aqui tienes un ejemplo en NET 7 (similar a NET 6) que utiliza

- [Curso NET > Winform > Starwars.App.WinformApp](https://github.com/fernandezja/curso-dotnet-web/tree/main/Unidad5/Starwars.Apps.WinFormsApp) donde podras ver que en se configura como indica la configuracion y se utiliza muy facilmente. En modo diseño se guarda en /properties/settings.settings pero cuando se compila es el archivo

Ejemplo en imagenes
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**TEMA 2: Leer appSettings.json desde Winform/Consola**
Y en este otro ejemplo (si bien es una consola podras ver como se lee un archivo de configuracion appSetting.json) que es valido para Winforms tambien

- [Curso NET > Console > Starwars.App.ConsoleApp](https://github.com/fernandezja/curso-dotnet-web/tree/main/Unidad5/Starwars.Apps.ConsoleApp) podras ver que se lee el appSettings.json (con las propiedades que se copie en release final)

Para que se copie al directorio de salida, la config queda

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appSettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Y para eso hacemos uso de estos componentes nugets

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Para leer la config de appSetting.json (del ejemplo anterior)

```
//Init: Config
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .AddJsonFile($"appSettings.json");

var config = configuration.Build();
var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("StarwarsConnectionString");
```

Aqui estoy obteniendo una "seccion especial" que es de cadenas de conexion, pero puedes obtener lo que necesitas

- [Configuracion > Ejemplo basico](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration#basic-example)

El ejemplo esta en la misma solucion tanto la consola como winform. Por si necesitas tenerlo para revisar.

- [Ejemplo Solucion Consola + Winform](https://github.com/fernandezja/curso-dotnet-web/tree/main/Unidad5)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía

Comment: Gracias, Jose A. Fernandez, ya lo tengo funcionando con esta super guia que me compartiste. Una pregunta para conocimiento general de mi parte amigo, con EF Core, todo lo trabajo con archivos .json, ya no se utilizan los app.config o web.config, solo esa pregunta tengo, para ya hice lo que necesitaba.

Comment: Estimado Alfredo, existen ["multiples maneras de configurar nuestras apps"](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration). Dependiendo del tipo de app (winform por ejemplo ya tiene su propio sistema) pero en todos los tipos de apps se pueden leer diferentes tipos de archivos (como app.config), por ejemplo en ambiente web con .NET Core (o NET 7/8) tenemos appSettings.json pero tambien el web.config para poder configurar el hosting como IIS o donde se ejecute. El enlace que envio mas arriba tiene una descripcion de todos los tipos.